# How to match 5 lines of text in any order using python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the following 6 lines within an XML.

```
string = '''[<Parameter name="Number of steps" type="unsignedInteger" value="10"/>
        <Parameter name="Type" type="unsignedInteger" value="1"/>
        <Parameter name="Object" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value"/>
        <Parameter name="Minimum" type="float" value="216.862"/>
        <Parameter name="Maximum" type="float" value="867.448"/>
        <Parameter name="log" type="bool" value="1"/>]*'''
```

I need to match all 6 lines but in any order, since the program that writes it seems to sometimes changes which lines goes where.

I'm trying the following code:

```
import re
re.findall('''            <Parameter name="Number of steps" type="unsignedInteger" value="10"/>
        <Parameter name="Type" type="unsignedInteger" value="1"/>
        <Parameter name="Object" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value"/>
        <Parameter name="Minimum" type="float" value="216.862"/>
        <Parameter name="Maximum" type="float" value="867.448"/>
        <Parameter name="log" type="bool" value="1"/>''',string)
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix my problem?

------------Edit------------------------

To be more specific I have many XMl's which I am reading as text and I need to extract some information using regex.

```
        scan_parameters=re.findall('''    <Task key="(.*)" name="Scan" type="scan" scheduled="true" updateModel="false">
  <Report reference="(.*)" target="(.*)" append="0" confirmOverwrite="0"/>
  <Problem>
    <Parameter name="Subtask" type="unsignedInteger" value="5"/>
    <ParameterGroup name="ScanItems">
      <ParameterGroup name="ScanItem">
        (<Parameter name="Maximum" type="float" value="(.*)"/>|
        <Parameter name="Minimum" type="float" value="(.*)"/>|
        <Parameter name="Number of steps" type="unsignedInteger" value="10"/>|
        <Parameter name="Object" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=(.*),Vector=Reactions\[(.*)\],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=(.*),Reference=Value"/>|
        <Parameter name="Type" type="unsignedInteger" value="1"/>|
        <Parameter name="log" type="bool" value="1"/>){6}
      </ParameterGroup>
    </ParameterGroup>''',copasiML_original)
```

I need this to return a list containing the values that were in (.*).

Comment: If the tags can be in any order, then you have 120 possible orders, and will need 120 different regular expressions to match them all. Just one of the many, many reasons not to try to use regular expressions to parse XML.

Comment: If you need exact string matches, can't you just use string operations? Split into lines, sort the lists and compare them or something similar? Do you actually need to match the content, or just the tag format? Be more specific.

Comment: if you are trying to extract particular fields, then use `beautiful soup` not regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive look ahead if you really need to do these using regex as follows:

```
(?=.*\[<Parameter name="Number of steps" type="unsignedInteger" value="10"/>)(?=.*<Parameter name="Type" type="unsignedInteger" value="1"/>)(?=.*<Parameter name="Object" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions\[v1\],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value"/>)(?=.*<Parameter name="Minimum" type="float" value="216.862"/>)(?=.*<Parameter name="Maximum" type="float" value="867.448"/>)(?=.*<Parameter name="log" type="bool" value="1"/>\]\*)
```

However, notice that this won't match if there are any newlines between each statements. If you have newlines between them, replace `(?=.*` with `(?=[.\s]*` otherwise you can just remove newlines before passing it to match

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lkLKkFrH9dN2O-3Z)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care whether they are repeated or some are missing—only that there are five matches in a row:

```
/(text1|text2|text3|text4|text5){5}/
```